# Spilled wine on my Macbook Pro (2017) trackpad

Tags: keyboard, trackpad, damage

I spilled wine on the trackpad. Not too much and it didn't go through my keyboard. I dried it out with a napkin and a hairdryer. After about two hours, on pressing the trackpad a little bit of wine seeped out from the side (very less). I turned it off and left it upside down in an L shaped mode. It seems to be working fine and I don't feel any stickiness on the trackpad.
Any tips on what to do next?

Comment: see this for a cautionary tale... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219053/no-sound-speakers-jack-microphones-dead-after-spilling-water

Comment: Also see this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297833/119271  but most importantly...get it cleaned and dried before you risk it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still concerned about whether it will still work, I would recommend taking it to an Apple Store or other computer store. It seems fine though. And maybe for the future, don't put drinks next to your computer :)