# Can I disable the left CMD key and not the right CMD key?

Tags: keyboard

I have developed a case of "texting-thumb". Something that contributes to this is that I use my left hand to hit CMD-C, CMD-V, CMD-T, CMD-Q, and CMD-W frequently. To the point where my resting position on the keyboard is with my thumb curled under my hand on the CMD key.

I want to disable the left CMD key to untrain my left hand from using it and let my right hand hit it. Can I selectively disable one key in software in MacOS?

I know I can pop the keycap off but I prefer to not have loose parts running around if I can avoid it.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297832/how-to-disable-left-command-key is a similar question but the cause and solution to spilled beer is different than a repetitive use . That question also does not have a software solution.

Comment: I wonder if this might allow you to disable a CMD key in software... https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/