# Clean Macbook 12" key contact

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, repair

A few months ago on a flight, I stupidly put a glass of wine next to my immaculate Macbook. The inevitable happened and half a glass of red wine was split directly onto the keyboard. In a combined two handed move which I now call the "Macbook Save", I held down the power button to turn it off and tipped the Macbook to the side and the wine ran out of the keyboard.

I cried a little and then left it switched off in my bag until I got home two weeks later. I was surprised to find that it was in full working order but the <kbd>U</kbd> key has been a little temperamental. Today I took the key cover and butterfly mechanism out to find the culprit of my intermittent key, some red wine staining.

Is this slightly rubbery part removable? I'd rather not force it and break a nearly perfectly functioning keyboard. If not I was going to try to get some tiny amounts of pure alcohol under there to try and remove the red wine deposits. Is this a terrible idea? Looking at keyboard replacement videos I can see how it managed to survive relatively unscathed as the keyboard looks glued in!

[image]

Comment: See this for some insight and some advice to heed.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219053/no-sound-speakers-jack-microphones-dead-after-spilling-water

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of the referenced existing question. This keyboard is very different to all the keyboards that have come before it. On older Macbooks they have rubber cups which can be removed and cleaned. It's looking unlikely but I wanted to know specifically if anybody has experience with this the newer low profile keys and their cup part...