# MacBook Pro on table with water

Tags: macbook-pro

So I spilled water on my table last night and thought I cleaned it all up but apparently not. I didn’t see there was still water on the table and I went to put my MacBook on the water. I only realised it was on water when my screen started going green and glitchy. I immediately shut the lid and wiped off water on the bottom them opened it to turn it off then put it on some uncooked rice. Will this be ok or is there anything else I can do to save it

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275 for a cautionary tale.

Comment: @Tetsujin are you saying that if a (mac) laptop gets water in it then it is 100% guaranteed to be knackered / broken / dead?

Comment: @SolarMike - There's no guarantee of anything; which is why it needs stripping & cleaning to be certain. I've only ever killed one in 30 years of computing; that was an external keyboard with no visible means of disassembly; so I went for all the 'other tricks' to try dry it - with zero success, it went in the trash. Even tap water will corrode the circuit tracks &/or cause shorts which will either blow components or cause further corrosion. Getting the battery out should be the prime focus; with the power still connected, your chances are even slimmer.

Comment: @Tetsujin as I pointed out in my answer, I successfully sorted one which had water in it and failed with the ones with beer and wine... Perhaps time is also a factor - I had the water one drying inside 5 minutes... It sounds like your keyboard was left to corrode for a while...

Comment: @SolarMike - in fact I had it sprayed in dehydrant inside 2 minutes, to no avail - presumably I just couldn't get the same penetration the water had achieved. It had swallowed about half a pint. Still, that was a £40 keyboard - you want to take the same risk on your £1500 laptop... up to you.

Comment: @Tetsujin my laptop is much more than that... But I have not done that to any of mine...

Comment: well hey, my laptop works now after all. i'll be sure not to mysteriously spill water on my laptop table again

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have a plastic box put the mac & rice in that, shut the lid and put it somewhere "gently" warm. 24 hours minimum - give it a chance as it sounds like water got deep in...

But if you can get it to someone who can take the cover off to clean and dry it out that would be better...

Be thankful it was not beer or (white) wine - they leave residues that make it very unlikely that they start again (guess how I know :), done 3 water, wine & beer - only one that survived was the one with water...), but water there is a chance...

Best of luck with it.

Comment: is there a chance the rice could go inside my Mac through those vent holes or is it fine

Comment: place the mac on a small plate to keep it off the rice - it won't suck rice in as it is not running...

Comment: so I was impatient and decided to open up my laptop.looks like it’s fine now, no green screen or whatever. Do you think it’s safe to charge or should I shut it down and charge or Putcitnback in the rice

Comment: Your choice, there still could be moisture in there...

Comment: Putting it in rice & hoping is about the worst thing you can do. Basically you're just leaving it to continue shorting out until it dries.