# Is there a way to power up a 2017 MacBook Pro (non Touch Bar) with a bad keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, startup, power

A friend of mine has asked me to take a look and see if I can bring their 2017 MacBook Pro (13", non Touch Bar) back to life. Apparently the cause of death was that a glass of wine was spilled on the keyboard.

I've cleaned off the remnants of dried juice and things look clean enough, but the machine will not power up. While I presume there must be a short inside (I haven't cracked it open yet), I suspect that perhaps the keyboard is gunked up and maybe the power button doesn't work.

So before I go through the trouble of tearing this thing apart, is there a way to get it to boot (or at least show signs of life) presuming it has a dead keyboard? Would it respond to an external Apple USB keyboard perhaps (from a 2008 Mac Pro, so <kbd>Eject</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> I'd assume)?

Comment: Considering it's still safe to connect to a power source, plug in the charger and try by holding down Shift + Control + Option keys (left side) along with the Power key and then release them at the same time.

Comment: These devices usually power on when the display is opened. So my hunch is something more severe than the keyboard is damaged.

Comment: It's damaged - you must take it in for service.  See this [cautionary tale](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219053/no-sound-speakers-jack-microphones-dead-after-spilling-water) because starting it could make things much worse.