# battery is not charging after liquid contact

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, charger

After spilling a tea into the macbook 11 i have disassembled it. Cleaned everyhing with IPA and brush. Put together. Macbook is working but charger does not charge. LED does not light. System says it does not charge, source of power adapter. There is small icon of battery with flash saying 2%. I have changed I/O Board, battery, performed NVRAM/SMC reset. Still behave the same. No change.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Take it to a professional. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275 At least you didn't just put it in rice & hope for the best, you took positive, useful  action, but the chances are something shorted out & was damaged long before you could take it apart.

Comment: Different symptoms than the duplicate question but the answer is applicable here, too.

Comment: *Cleaned everyhing with IPA* - I guess that *IPA* doesn't mean *India Pale Ale* here ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - That was my first thought too… which made me chuckle quite a bit. But no, it also stands for Isopropyl Alcohol, which is more alcoholic, but less tasty ;-))