# How to remove water which has into the screen of my iPhone?

Tags: display, iphone

I have Apple IPhone 6 and it accidentally fell into water and some of water went inside the screen,
[image]

[image]

I got no problem with touch screen, even at the places where I got water touch screen is working well. I tried one more thing, I took the screen shot and send it to the other phone, and I found there was no *water mark* when viewed in the other phone.

Is there something I can do to remove that *water mark* from my screen?

Comment: Take it to a professional immediately. You have no idea how far the water penetrated. Putting it in rice & hoping for the best is the worst possible move. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275 for a cautionary tale.

Comment: @Tetsujin The incident happened several days back, I think almost 20 days ago. So, I think my phone is quite safe as I have got no problem till now, but your advice is correct I should take to some professional but due to lockdown I cannot take it there.

Comment: *So, I think my phone is quite safe..*  That's probably the worst thing you can do;  assume it's ok.  Either way, to get the water out, you need to disassemble it.  Unless you have those skills, you need to take it in.

Comment: @Tetsujin Should I use hair-drier or some thing other? Was your rice example a joke or is it really a possible solution in these cases?

Comment: @Allan Yes you’re right

Comment: [Using rice to repair liquid damaged devices](https://youtu.be/yPeITOz2_YM)

Comment: No idea whether or not this will help your situation, but on a few occasions when I've gotten water in an electronic assembly that couldn't be taken apart this has worked: **dry heat & [hygroscopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygroscopy) material** Think toaster oven at 120degF & rice... yes, [rice is hygroscopic](https://www.scribd.com/document/95124477/Rice-is-a-Hygroscopic-Material). I'm not saying this is the *best* thing to do, but if your options are limited, maybe worth consideration.

Comment: @Seamus Can you please give a careful guide of that toaster oven method?

Comment: I would if I had one. It's not a precise procedure: cover the assembly with a hygroscopic material (rice if that's all you have), put it in an oven at very low heat for an hour. Look for signs of improvement or degradation. If it's better, keep going, if it's worse, stop.