# Coffee spilled on 2018 Touch Bar MBP. Still working with some problems. What to do?

Tags: macbook-pro

Almost a week ago I spilled a full cup of coffee on my Macbook Pro 2018 with Touch Bar. Coffee is spilled mostly left-ish side and it was without sugar but some milk. For now nothing major happened and it is working almost good but clicking on left side of trackpad doesn't working. I can move cursor, tap to click is working but no click sound on left side. And one USB-C port on the left is problematic. It's working mostly but when I move the cable or device on that port the connection loses briefly and returns back. Keyboard is working totally normal and there is no other issues for now. 6 months of warranty left but I don't even now if the spill already voids my warranty. So now I am in between opening the case and clean inside of it or wait till my warranty end.

What do you recommend for me and if I you think that I need to open and clean inside what can I use to clean water, coffee, fat etc. ? I have all the tools for opening the case and I am experienced with it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

"Recently"… unless it was in the last 5 minutes, you likely missed your chance.
The absolute first thing to do is stop using it, disconnect the power, including the battery, strip it down & start to dry up as much as possible.

Don't hope it will be OK.
Don't put it in rice & expect it will just get better.
Don't plug it back in to see if it still works.

Your two main enemies are short-circuit & corrosion.

Any liquid containing a high percentage of water will immediately short-circuit anything it touches, potentially causing component damage or even fire.

Any non-pure liquid will then start to corrode the delicate circuitry, quite rapidly in the presence of electricity.

The faster you can get the power removed & the circuits cleaned using isopropyl alcohol, the better the chance your machine will survive.

For additional reading -
[No sound (speakers/jack) + microphone's dead after spilling water](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219053/no-sound-speakers-jack-microphones-dead-after-spilling-water)
&
[What procedure should be followed post spilling fluids onto a MacBook keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392674/what-procedure-should-be-followed-post-spilling-fluids-onto-a-macbook-keyboard)

Comment: Follow this advice.  Don’t use the generic 70% stuff either, you need the 90% (or better) isopropyl alcohol.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should check your warranty status [here](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/). Then, as a person who spilled an energy drink on my own MacBook-Pro (but actually newer with another type of the keyboard), I advise to clean and dry the surface without opening inside. Do **NOT** use a hairdryer or any stuff like that. Only towels etc. And **GO** to the service center (official ofc) to let them check your MacBook status). Unfortunately, it will cost you some money but MacBook's design is quite complicated and wasting even a minute would lead to even bigger problems (-> more money to repair it)

Comment: A water-spill is not a warranty repair. It's an insurance claim. https://support.apple.com/HT201880

Comment: @Tetsujin I posted that link for gkon because it seems he doesn't know about it and it's helpful to check your warranty status anyway. And also I actually got full keyborad replaced after spilling water on it for free without any additional insurances etc. I paid only for checking its condition. Maybe that's because it happened in a week after purchasing it but that's the fact. It's worth trying :)

Comment: Actually it was nearly a week ago and I am using it since then. It was an important point so I edited my question. I just dried it from outside for minutes. But no luck for powering off because while I cleaning it kept powering on continuously. Maybe it was because of the trackpad.