# My MacBook Pro doesn't recognize the battery after minor liquid spill

Tags: macbook-pro

Hello and thank you in advance to everyone that will try to help me.

My MacBook Pro get water damaged with some drops of water on the left/up side and, as it should do in this cases, i rapidly shutted down and reversed it.

The laptop works perfectly fine with the exception of it not recognizing the battery, thus the laptop only turns on while being connected to the power cord. The battery icon on the top right displays an X with "No battery available". This is mirrored in the System Information interface under Power, where all values for this section display "No" and "0" (as in the battery is not recognized). If i remove the power cord it goes on kind of a sleep state because if i re-plug the cord it wakes so it doesn’t shut down.

I have tried SMC Reset and this made no difference. I’ve also tried cleaning the NVRAM/PRAM without any luck.

I’ve also tried a method described on a discussion on this site that consist on removing the battery, press 10 sec the power button, plug the magsafe while pushing power and then plug the battery in. With this method the MacBook turns on WITHOUT the power cord (so the battery is working), with the airfan at max speed but the battery icon on the top right still displays an X.

I’ve also purchased a new battery and replaced the old one but nothing changed.

I know that it is near impossible to diagnose what is wrong with the laptop via the forum, but what are the options? There are any other thing i can try do to or the only solution is asking to a service provider?

Answer (score 1):

That needs dismantling for cleaning and as soon as possible.

The damage will likely get worse and the « loquid » will also make a difference, as the impurities can become electrically conductive and cause more problems over time.

Take it to a service centre or a professional.

Comment: The accident occured on Tuesday so i think it's dryed and can't get worse.

Comment: Sure it can. Your first enemy is liquid; it shorts out components which if still powered may break components not even actually wet. Your second is corrosion… that's the 'sneak up behind & break things after you thought they were dry'. You made several errors 1) you tipped it over, causing water to go in places it hadn't already. 2) you didn't immediately remove the battery. 3) You imagined leaving it to dry would somehow magically improve it. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275 for a cautionary tale.

Comment: Funny, I have just visited a mate who repairs macs for a living and he has a basement full of spare parts: working displays with liquid damaged lower case sections, spare keyboards while the motherboards were fried, spare mother boards with keyboards fried etc etc. Up to you if you want to get it repaired before it is too late or order a new one now.